# Unit Test cases running very slow on my Mac machine

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

This started happening from past few months that my grails spock unit test cases have slowed down and eventually take 20-30 minutes.

This started happening before my upgrade to EI captain version and continued even after update.

I remember not changing any settings for it expect one thing. I some times use grails 2.5, other times use 2.3.8.

Test cases that are slow are in grails 2.3.8.

It's been a good time I spent on this but in vain.

I also tested on other machine to observe whether the issue is on my machine only or not.

These are running slow only on my machine.

Please let me know if this belongs to other stackoverflow website.

Reason for posting here is : everything else except test cases is working fast and perfectly.

**Edit:** Was going through the BuildConfig.groovy
After commenting line below test cases ran like cutting melt butter.

> grails.project.fork.test = false

I tried with changing it to `false` and same as above happened i.e. ran smoothly. But in end it stopped with following error.

[image]